# Could Nitinol (or similar super-elastic materials) be used to make a flexible gun nozzle/supressor?

Tags: science-based, physics, guns

I don't know if I should ask this here on Physics, but here we go.

The Context:

A certain secret society made a silencer to take down targets in the middle of crowds without being noticed.

The Idea:

So, one of the characteristics of Nitinol is super-elasticity under certain temperatures and thus, bend under specific amount of forces.

Taking this into consideration, it would be used in, let's say, a pistol with a flexible opening at nozzle so the gases stay inside the gun instead of escaping and making a lot of noise. Turning this into some kind of suppressor/silencer.

However, even if the bullet didn't irreversible destroyed the flexible nozzle/suppressor/silencer, I don't know if it would be enough to trap the gases, since the gases have more energy than the projectile.

And depending on the level of engineering required, it would be easier to simply shut the barrel with electronic activated valves. No?

Comment: I think I would notice if the fellow next to me in the crowd started screaming in agony "AAAH I'VE BEEN SHOT BY THAT GUY! STOP HIM! HELP ME!" and bleeding copiously before collapsing. I think a lot of people around us would notice, too. It's much harder to kill somebody quickly than movies would lead you to believe...especially if your assassin is trying to use a pistol in a crowd without the weapon being seen. Hard to aim that way.

Comment: @user535733 - maybe the victim has underclothes with flexible openings that keep his blood and guts inside, and a mask with a flexible opening to keep his agonized fussing inside.  Flexible openings are all the rage!

Comment: If I'd noticed this was tagged for hard science I wouldn't have answered -- and I don't think it can be answered in a way that's acceptable for that tag.  Perhaps should be "science based" instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why they'd bother.

[AAI Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAI_Corporation) (using a Smith & Wesson Model 29 frame) made a "silent" *revolver* (the ["Quiet Special Purpose Revolver"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_%26_Wesson_Model_29)) for use in tunnels during the Viet Nam conflict; it had a standard-seeming cylinder and barrel, but the barrel had a smaller bore than the cylinder.  The cartridges were a load of small tungsten shot (barely subsonic, to avoid "sonic boom" noise) over a hard wad, and when fired, the shot would exit via the barrel, but the wad would be captured, sealing the gas inside the cartridge.

No exotic materials, no super-tech electronics, no new inventions, other than developing a load that would be reliably lethal at close range but not damage the gun when 100% of the gas was trapped.  One could even modify an existing revolver.

No, not truly silent -- but the vast bulk of the noise from a gunshot is the gas exiting the barrel.  Rather than try to muffle that by releasing the gas slowly (as a suppressor does), trapping the gas gave a sound level similar to a suppressed .22 LR -- but without the need to aim with high precision (the tunnel rats this was made for worked without lights, for the most part, because the enemy would gain more than the tunnel rat would from a light).

***(Please don't try this at home -- get the load wrong, and your revolver will become a grenade in your hand.)***

Comment: It'd be also beneficial to use subsonic ammunition, so that there's no supersonic bang caused by the bullet.

Comment: The S&W was in fact subsonic.  Most revolvers without "Magnum" in the cartridge name are even with regular ammunition.  I'll edit that in, though.

Comment: FYI, the QSPR project was canceled in large part because it had a maximum lethal range of about 10 meters and at 110 dB, it was just about as loud as a traditionally suppressed .22LR pistol which has an effective range of just over 100m.  So while the QSPR does trap the gas, it  is not as effective of a weapon system as traditional silencing.

Comment: For its intended use, 10 m was just fine -- you couldn't identify a target further than that in a tunnel, without lights, anyway.  And, firing shot from a short, unchoked smooth bore, it didn't require the precision aiming a .22 would (also not possible in the dark).  At 10 m, it ought to have patterned at a foot or so across.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I suppose it matters why you need a silenced weapon.  The OP did not say what he needs a silenced weapon for; so, I just wanted to point out the limitations of the QSPR vs traditional silencing in case it applies to his use case... though now that I think about it, the QSPR does have some advantages too like 100% flash suppression and spread.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem A: It would make for a bad gun

The gas from your gun exerts a lot of force... it is where the slug gets its own force from after all.  Any material soft enough to let the slug pass through without really slowing it down will also allow most of the gas to escape without slowing it down either.  Inversely, and material stiff enough to pinch off the gas will also significantly slow down your slug seriously limiting the efficiency of the weapon.  The use of [Nitinol](https://www.imagesco.com/articles/nitinol/04.html) would seem to fix this problem because it means the barrel only contracts once heated, but heat takes time to transfer; so, while it may not pinch the slug, the heat will not have time to permeate the alloy before the gases all escape.

### Problem B: The gas escapes faster than the barrel can contract

Let's pretend you don't wait for the heat of the bullet to heat up the alloy, but instead use electronics to instantly activate the barrel.  Most small arms have a mussel velocity of about [250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.22_Short)-[1300](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.220_Swift)m/s. While I can not find any exact specifications on how fast Nitinol can contract, it is safe to say it can not contract nearly this fast. The accelerations caused by elastic materials are compounded by the cross section of the material; so, the small cross section of your barrel means that even if it contracted as fast as other materials we consider to have a high speed of elasticity, it still could not pinch off at more than a few m/s.  So, the barrel could not contract fast enough to meaningfully impede the gases escape.

### Problem C: It would make the gun louder, not more quite

When you consider both problems A and B together, we can assume that your flexible gun will never do more than partially pinch off the air flow no matter what you make it out of.  Imagine the tip of your gun like a garden hose.  When you put your thumb over part of the end, the same amount of water comes out, but it comes out much faster.  Likewise, if the hole closes off, but only partially, then you will have a narrower, faster gas jet. This would give the gun a louder and higher pitch noise than it would otherwise have.

Comment: Very few small arms approach 1500 m/s, and most long guns barely touch 1000 (if they even get there).  I don't know of a pistol that even gets close to 1000 m/s (fastest pistol bullet in production is the 7.5x28 BRNO, at almost 700 m/s).  Subsonic ammunition is very commonly used with suppressors anyway, and is readily available in common pistol cartridges like 9mm (.45 ACP standard ball is subsonic, as are .32 ACP and .380 ACP, and .22 LR from a short barrel).

Comment: @ZeissIkon You are correct.  I should have questioned that source because as soon as I reread it, it sounded very wrong (the source probably mixed up fps and m/s).  I've redid the velocity range to that between a .22 SR and .220 swift which should pretty well encompass nearly all modern rounds. but the point still stands that this is orders of magnitude greater than how fast you can expect the material to contract.

Comment: "orders of magnitude greater than how fast you can expect the material to contract." that, I will not argue with.  You can find video of Nitinol resetting when held in steam from a kettle, it's quick but not bullet fast.